# We need to modify [mod]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[mod](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mod) has no definition, but 19 questions where the tag has varying meanings:

- modification of various and sundry things
- what appears to be a reference to MOD format recording
- the Excel function
- something related to perl (I'm not a programmer)
- mod_wsgi, whatever that is
- a few others that I'm still trying to figure out what they might refer to

It obviously needs work, but it may require users with various backgrounds to clean this one up.

Comment: mod_perl and mod_wsgi are apache modules.